# Having trouble with rdiff-backup

Tags: scripts, backup, rdiff-backup

I'm having trouble with automation of rdiff-backup. There are 2 issues right now.

Script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
​# This is backup script for rdiff-backup

# Backup command
​rdiff-backup --include-globbing-filelist /home/administrator/backup.list / /mnt/backup/dst

#Checking rdiff-backup command success / error
status=$?
if [ $status != 0 ]; then
        # Append error message in ~/backup.log file
        echo "rdiff-backup exit Code: $status - Command Unsuccessful">>~/varundus.log;
        exit 1;
fi
# Remove incremental backup files older than two weeks
​rdiff-backup --force --remove-older-than 1W /mnt/backup/dst/
```

The first problem, is that the terminal is giving an error when executing:

```
rdiff-backup --force --include-globbing-filelist backup.list / /mnt/backup/dst/
```

Error:

```
Found interrupted initial backup. Removing...
Fatal Error: Last selection expression:
Command-line include glob: /var/www
only specifies that files be included.  Because the default is to
include all files, the expression is redundant.  Exiting because this
probably isn't what you meant.
```

What's causing that?

The second error, is that if i run my script, i get:

```
./inc-backup.sh: line 5: ​rdiff-backup: command not found
./inc-backup.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./inc-backup.sh: line 9: `​if [ $status != 0 ]; then'
```

How come, that shell can't find the command, but if i enter it manually it works (with errors of first section). Can somebody please explain what im doing wrong? Thanks :)